# Why does my shared event handler think the handler's nominative "owner" is always the sender?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, radio-button

I've got an event handler that is shared by all of my radiobuttons:

```
private void radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb == radioButtonPackers)
    {
        team = NFCNorth.Packers;
    } else if (rb == radioButtonBears)
    {
        team = NFCNorth.Bears;
    } else if . . .
}
```

rb is always seen as being radioButtonPackers, even after I've checked the radioButtonBears, radioButtonVikings, or radioButtonLions radiobutton.

Do I have to do something like:

```
if (radioButtonPackers.Checked)
{
    team = NFCNorth.Packers;
}
else if (radioButtonBears.Checked)
{
    team = NFCNorth.Bears;
}
. . .
```

?

Comment: How certain are you that the event handler is *really* shared between all the buttons? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: From the Designer.cs file:
this.radioButtonPackers.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButtonBears.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButtonLions.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged);
this.radioButtonVikings.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take note of `rb.Checked`, but in my experience you'll get an "unchecked" event before you get the "checked" one anyway. Here's a short but complete example which works:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b1 = new RadioButton { Text = "Button 1" };
        var b2 = new RadioButton { Text = "Button 2" };

        EventHandler handler = (sender, args) => {
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton) sender;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",
                button.Text,
                button.Checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked");
        };

        b1.CheckedChanged += handler;
        b2.CheckedChanged += handler;

        var form = new Form {
            Controls = {
                new FlowLayoutPanel {
                    FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
                    Controls = { b1, b2 }
                }
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }    
}
```

If you click on Button 1 then on Button 2, you'll see:

```
Button 1 Checked    
Button 1 Unchecked    
Button 2 Checked
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in that way, actually. It has to receive like a `sender` any radiobutton clicked. Your confusion **may** be related to a fact that `radioButtonPackers_CheckedChanged` you can recieve twice, in case if radiobuttons are grouped, so when one is clicked the current one

- first becomes unchecked (so raise event)
- after comes event of a "new" radiobutton

Comment: So is the takeaway that "only do stuff `if (rb.Checked)`"? :)

Comment: @AKX: it depends if OP needs to do something **only** in case of "checked", may be there is something that has to be happen also if some `radiobutton` becomes unchecked..

Comment: but for this case (and looking at the accepted answer) this seemed to be the case :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to look at the `.Checked` property.

The first time you click one of the radio buttons, a single `CheckedChanged` event is fired (for turning "on" the button). Then, when you click a different radio button in the same group, there are two `CheckedChanged` events that are fired, one for the unchecking of the first radio button, and the other for the checking of the second.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your code is working correctly but you're seeing the CheckedChanged event being fired for the previously selected RadioButton when it changes from being checked to unchecked, before the just selected RadioButton gets its check (and the event fires for it).